# How to get Expo Rail ticket?

Tags: trains, tickets, sri-lanka

I wanted to buy tickets for Expo Rail Sri Lanka from Colombo to Nanoya (Nuwara Eliya) in December. I checked their website, and can’t find anything. Is it possible to buy at the station?

Answer (score 4):

There are big "Book Online" buttons all over their website, but more to the point, you cannot get an Expo Rail ticket because Expo Rail is out of business, and has not operated since September 2017. In fairness, there does not seem to have been much coverage in the English-language press I can find online, but the notice on their website as of November 2017 reads as follows:

> We thank you for visiting Exporail.lk
>
> We were Sri Lanka's first private carriage operator connecting to various destinations and did our best to uplift the standards of the Rail Experience!
>
> We worked dedicatedly, proactively and diligently to combat many factors to ensure our passengers had a comfortable ride with a great experience.
>
> Due to various PESTEL factors that surround this industry our company was compelled to freeze operations and then subsequently had to shut down.
>
> This is indeed Sad and an Unfortunate moment as our journey had got De-Railed! We had a great run. We gave it our best. We really did!
>
> Thanks for supporting our venture. Thanks for all your blessings and wishes. Our team will miss serving you!